# MySQL get difference between two smallest dates in different records grouped on

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with the following structure and example records:

[image]

I want to figure out how to get the difference between the two earliest created_at records for each name. It is a possibility the name only has one record, in which case any default value is okay, like 0, -1, or NULL. Running it on the above record I would anticipate a result like so:

```
nameA, 31
nameB, 59
nameC, -1
```

I can't think of any clean ways to do this purely in SQL. I thought about joining the table on itself, grouping on name, and selecting the min created_at from the first join, but I don't know how to then select the second minimum to bring it down to a single record.

Thanks

Comment: what's your mysql version?

Answer (score 0):

One option, using a CTE with `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY created_at) rn
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT
    name,
    DATEDIFF(MAX(created_at), MIN(created_at)) AS diff_in_days
FROM cte
WHERE rn <= 2
GROUP BY
    name
ORDER BY
    name;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mysql version didn't support window function you can try to use correlated-subquery make row number.

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT t1.name,DATEDIFF(t1.max_dt,t1.min_dt) value
FROM (
  select name,
        max(create_date) max_dt,
        min(create_date) min_dt
  from (
        SELECT *,(SELECT COUNT(*) 
                  FROM T tt 
                  WHERE tt.name = t1.name and t1.create_date >= tt.create_date) rn
        FROM T t1
  )  t1
  where rn <= 2
  group by name
) t1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9749d1/20/0)**:

```
|  name | value |
|-------|-------|
| NameA |    31 |
| NameB |    59 |
| NameC |     0 |
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `lead()` and `row_number():

```
select t.name,
       datediff(next_created_at, created_at) as diff_days
from (select t.*,
             lead(created_at) over (partition by name order by created_at) as next_created_at,
             row_number() over (partition by name order by created_at) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```